# OpenSSL read on non-blocking socket unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, https, openssl

I'm  implementing HTTPS server using OpenSSL and I've faced some strange behavior while reading a data. The following code I guess is illustrating the issue:

```cpp
char m_readBuffer[READ_BUFFER_SIZE];
std::vector<char> data;
bool readMore = true;
bool isError = false;

do
{
    SSL *ssl = m_sslClient[i];
    retval = SSL_read(ssl, m_readBuffer, READ_BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (retval <= 0)
    {
        int errorCode = SSL_get_error(ssl, retval);
        if (errorCode == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ)
        {
            readMore = false;
            isError = false;
        }
        else
        {
            readMore = false;
            isError = true;
            CloseClient(i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        data.insert(data.end(), m_readBuffer, m_readBuffer + retval);
    }
}
while(readMore == true);

if(isError == false)
{
    ProcessData(i, data);
}
```

The code works as expected, i.e. I read the data that a browser sends to me without any problem. But I've come to this code let's say experimentally. The code that boring me is the `SSL_read` return value. I can't (or I guess I can't) determine exactly when the data stream ended. The documentation says that `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` means that there is more data and I have to repeat reading. But by experience I came to the fact that if `SSL_read` return `-1` and then `SSL_get_error` returns `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` this indicates that there in no more data.

Ok, that works but I'm worried that this may be working incorrectly.

Is there a *right way* to determine that I read out all the data?